# Optimal Numpad in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a numpad.

The way I try to making the numpad is like:

```
class One:

 def __init__(self,c,msg):
     self.screen = c.calculator
     self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
     self.settings = c.settings
     self.width,self.height = 60,60 
     self.button_color = (230,230,230)
     self.text_color = (100,100,100)
     self.rect = pygame.Rect(30,600,self.width,self.height)
     self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS',20,bold=pygame.font.Font.bold)
     self._prep_msg(msg)

 def _prep_msg(self,msg):
     self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg,True,self.text_color,self.button_color)
     self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
     self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center 

 def draw_button(self):
     self.screen.fill(self.button_color,self.rect)
     self.screen.blit(self.msg)
```

This way is requires a lot of code, making one class each for like 9 numbers.

I hoping if there was more optimal way of making this numpad.

I think of making sprites but I don't know how I will change the text:

```
self.One = One(self,"1")
```

If there is something you can't understand please ask.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). You can instantiate a class multiple times. e.g.:

Create a `Button`. The position of the button is an argument to the constructor:

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, c, msg, x, y):                            # <--- x, y
        self.screen = c.calculator
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = c.settings
        self.width,self.height = 60,60 
        self.button_color = (230,230,230)
        self.text_color = (100,100,100)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)   # <--- x, y
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS',20,bold=pygame.font.Font.bold)
        self._prep_msg(msg)

    def _prep_msg(self,msg):
        self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg,True,self.text_color,self.button_color)
        self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
        self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center 

    def draw_button(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.button_color,self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.msg)
```

Create multiple [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of the class `Button`:

```py
self.button_one = Button(self, "1", 30, 600)
self.button_two = Button(self, "2", 100, 600)
```

Comment: @help Sorry, there must be a mistake in your code. The constructor has 4 arguments _c, msg, x, y_.

Comment: Yeah my bad , sorry.

Comment: @help I added some comments to the code in the answer.